# Adding characters of English pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I'd like to add chars of English pronunciation, such like "əɒˈæɪʒʃʊʌ". I've already tried to change the inputenc and the fotnenc, but nothing worked properly.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

Instead of `/ˈʃəʊ.vɪ.nɪ.zəm/`
I get `/[U+02C8][U+028A].v[U+026A].n[U+026A].zm/`.

With this I add "æ", however I would like to add the rest as well. I tried to use saleinput library with no result. How am I supposed to add these characters? I'll be very thankful for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should have a look at the `tipa` package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For IPA, the `tipa` package is the choice. Unfortunately, it doesn't come equipped with a translator from Unicode, so either you use its standard conventions, or have to define the translation yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{ˈ}{\textprimstress}
\newunicodechar{ʃ}{\textesh}
\newunicodechar{ə}{\textschwa}
\newunicodechar{ʊ}{\textupsilon}
\newunicodechar{ɪ}{\textsci}

\begin{document}

\textipa{/"S@U.vI.nI.z@m/}

\textipa{/ˈʃəʊ.vɪ.nɪ.zəm/}

\end{document}
```

[image]